# Notepad ++, Conditionally Replace CR LF

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file as follows:

```
Conduit 1 CRLF
10 CRLF
23 CRLF
Conduit 1 CRLF
22 CRLF
12 CRLF
etc.
```

With notepad ++ I am trying to determine what search/replace statements I can use to replace the CRLF with a tab but only when the following line does not start with Conduit.

The result I am looking for is as follows:

```
Conduit 1 tab 10 tab 23 CRLF
Conduit 1 tab 22 tab 12 CRLF
```

I know to use the \t in the replace and \r\n finds all of the CRLF but I am just unsure how to conditionally perform the replacement.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead:

**Find:**

```
\r\n(?!Conduit)
```

**Replace:**

```
\t
```

As you might guess, the find pattern simply looks ahead of the CRLF and asserts that the word `Conduit` does *not* start the next line.  Only in this case do we replace CRLF with a tab.

Follow the link below for a (canned) demo.  I don't know how to enter CRLF into the demo, so I left literal `CRLF` in the test data, as well as the regex, but you can see that it is working.

### Demo

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The find section does not work.  Notepad++ says "Can't find the text "\r\n(?!Conduit)"

Comment: @ChrisH Are you doing the find/replacement with regex mode _enabled_?  You'll need to do that because my find pattern includes a lookaround.

Comment: Tim, good catch.  I forgot to select regex mode.  Once I did, it worked exactly as you said it would.  Problem solved.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just format it into simple columns and rows you can do the following in the search and replace box (Ctrl + H).

Set it to Regular expression

Find what:

> (Conduit \d+)\r\n(\d+)\r\n(\d+)

Replace with:

> \1\t\2\t\3

Orgininal Input:

```
Conduit 1
10
23
Conduit 1
22
12
```

Produces:

```
Conduit 1   10  23
Conduit 1   22  12
```